# How to split one single row to multiple rows using html

Tags: html, powershell

I want to split the row value into multiple rows, as below,

Currently i'm getting the below output.
[Table structure which i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Vmx.png)

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| First Second Third...etc | Running Running Running...etc |

Expected Output :

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| First | Running |
| Second | Running |
| Third | Running |

Comment: place it in table with wrap with row and column and place borders

Comment: Please add more details (as input data etc.) and share your current script (in the question). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). (General) long shot; [`$hostInstances |ConvertTo-Html`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)

Comment: Probably as simple as creating an object array (one object per name=status) and using cmdlet `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment`, but any further advise is impossible because of the lack of details.

Comment: Hi all , i'm unable to add the powershell script in question.
$mbody = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.HostName}
$mbody1 = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.ServiceState}
# Creating the HTML Page
$Html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>  
table, th, td {  
  border: 1px solid black;  
}  
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<br>
HostInstances:
<table>
<tr style="background-color: #dddddd;">
    <th>HostInstance</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>$mbody</td>
 <td>$mbody1</td>
</tr>    
</table>
"@

Answer (score 0):

Add your script and then input data from your source this should auto add input if you get array error place echo data in object remove []and test again

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
.p{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
        <th style="background-color: #dddddd;">
             Name
         </th>
         <th class="p" style="background-color: #dddddd;">
            Status
         </th>
          </thead>
           <tbody>
         <?php   $mbody = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.HostName} $mbody1 = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.ServiceState} ?>
         <tr>
          <td><?php echo $hostInstance['HostName']; ?></td>
          <td class="p"><?php echo $hostInstance['ServiceState']; ?></td>      
            </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
       </tbody>
   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Weyers, I want to split the output using space , see this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Vmx.png

Comment: please explain how you would like to split the output in a different why than the example provided.

Comment: i think best will be if you can give us the code you have.

Comment: i'm using html inside powershell script.

Comment: Hi Weyers, 
here is the powershell script.
$mbody = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.HostName}
$mbody1 = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.ServiceState}
# Creating the HTML Page
$Html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>  
table, th, td {  
  border: 1px solid black;  
}  
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<br>
HostInstances:
<table>
<tr style="background-color: #dddddd;">
    <th>HostInstance</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>$mbody</td>
 <td>$mbody1</td>
</tr>    
</table>
"@

Answer (score 0):

clearly you intend to build a table, but the data is coming in grouped, is that really the problem? Why don't you create a table (since you know what the headers are for each column), give it an id and build it using JS? You can use JS functions to separate the inputs and then declare an array that takes the separate inputs. Then just create a variable that receives the html code with all the content. Then just change the html content of the table id.

I'll put an example below:

```js
var tabelaEmAndamento = '';

var input = {
   "values":[
      {"name":"First", "status":"Running"},
      {"name":"Second", "status":"Running"},
      {"name":"Third", "status":"Running"}
   ]
}

for (i in input.values) {
   tabelaEmAndamento += '<tr>'
         +'<td>'
            +'' + input.values[i].name + ''
         +'</td>'
         +'<td class="center">'
            +'' + input.values[i].status + ''
         +'</td>'
   +'</tr>'
}
$('#tabela-EmAndamento').html(tabelaEmAndamento);
```

```css
table {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
}

td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
}

.center {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr style="background-color: #dddddd;">
         <th>
            Name
         </th>
         <th class="center">
            Status
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tabela-EmAndamento">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Clearly you have complicated simple table in to something scary.

Comment: I understand that he wants to separate the input he is receiving. For this he will need to separate the input with JS, I showed a way how he can show the table building with JS.

Comment: yes and i do understand that your way will be a better a rout to go with more complex information that needs to be passed but clearly the information that needs to go in to this table is basic. in the question he stated html that tells me it need to be basic.

Comment: $mbody = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.HostName}
$mbody1 = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.ServiceState}
# Creating the HTML Page
$Html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>  
table, th, td {  
  border: 1px solid black;  
}  
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<br>
HostInstances:
<table>
<tr style="background-color: #dddddd;">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>$mbody</td>
 <td>$mbody1</td>
</tr>    
</table>
"@

Comment: I'm using powershell script to from table structure , see the above script.

Comment: But understand, he's saying he's getting this value: "Running Running Running...etc" and wants to show it separately. If the value is RECEIVED, you need to separate. If it's just built, you're right in your statement.

Comment: ok the question said html that tells me it is basic. but his code he gave needs script. Yes JS will be the answer .